# Using div elements in an R markdown document

Tags: html, r

I'm trying to put two bordered tables side by side **with a gap in between** using HTML in an R markdown document. When I copy the HTML for [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_table_side_by_side&stacked=h) in W3Schools I get this as an HTML output from R Markdown:
[image]

The proper rendering, as in the W3Schools link, should be this:

[image]

Is there something I need to change in the code or a different way to solve it? I've tried writing HTML to do it as one table, but because of a quirk of CSS in R Markdown with rendering table borders (you need to use `border="1"` in the `table` element and so styling is a challenge) that doesn't work

Comment: You haven't shown us what you put in the document.

Comment: I mentioned it’s in the W3Schools link

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to save the html as an external file and then include it in the R markdown file using an iframe. To do this copy and paste the html from the w3s example and save it in your working directory with a `.html` extension.

Then you need to make the iframe large enough by defining its height and width. If you want to get rid of the border line around the iframe you can add this css to the iframe `border-width:0px` That alone will get the tables to display correctly and looks like this:

[image: no yaml changes]

If you want to remove more of rmarkdown's default css you can add

```
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: null
```

to the R markdown's yaml. Here's what that looks like:

[image: Yaml Changes]

Here's what the R markdown file looks like assuming you saved the html in your working directory in a file called `side_by_side_tables.html`

```
---
title: "Untitled"
date: '2023-03-25'
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: null
---


<iframe src="side_by_side_tables.html" width="100%"  height="400px" style="border-width:0px" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks - just using ```theme: null``` has actually worked for me because I can use the proper CSS styles to do it as one table